# Bash is not returning $? variable correctly

Tags: bash

Bash is not returning $? variable correctly when command output is assigned to a local variable:

```
test() {
  aaa=$(eval "timeout 1s sleep 5s")
  echo $? # echoes 124 (!=0 as expected)

  local aaa=$(eval "timeout 1s sleep 5s")
  echo $? # echoes 0
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`local` is a command by itself (it is a shell builtin), so you are getting the return value of `local`, not the return value the pipeline in your command substitution. You might consider declaring the variable local prior to assignment, which will avoid having to call the `local` builtin during the same pipeline as the command substitution, which will avoid obscuring the exit code of your command:

```
foo() {
    local bar
    bar=$(baz)
    echo $?
}
```